# Why using anonymous field in struct enables the type to satisfy interface when there's no methods written?

Tags: go

For a type to satisfy an interface, the type needs to implement the methods defined in the interface.

However, in the code snippet below, `myStruct` does not have any methods written, but by using `someInterface` as anonymous field, it satisfies `someInterface`.

Can someone help explain why is it? Thank you.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type someInterface interface {
    method1(int) string
    method2(string) string
}

type myStruct struct {
    someInterface
    body int
}

func main() {
    var foo someInterface
    bar := myStruct{}

    foo = bar // why no compile error??

    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Comment: When you embed a type in a struct, the embedded type's methods get *promoted* to the struct type. When methods get "promoted" then you can invoke them directly from the struct type instead of through the embedded field, i.e. instead of writing `bar.someInterface.method1()` you can now write `bar.method1()`. So essentially this allows the struct type to satisfy the interface without having to implement it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myStruct` embeds `someInterface`, so it has all the methods defined in that interface. That also means, `myStruct` has a field called `someInterface`, which is not initializes, so calling `bar.method1` will panic. You have to initialize it before using it.

```
bar:=myStruct{}
bar.someInterface=someInterfaceImpl{}
bar.method1(0)
bar.method2("")
```